# Are all transactions, whether SegWit or non-SegWit, part of the commitment in a coinbase transaction?

Tags: segregated-witness, coinbase-transaction, merkle-tree, witness-commitment

A merkle root in a block header is a way to commit all transactions in that block. However, since it does not cover transaction witness data, another commitment needs to be made in a coinbase transaction. The only difference is now instead of a TXID we create a WTXID that additionaly includes the marker, tag and witness data. For non-SegWit transactions, it is necessary to use the old serialization format so their TXID is equal to WTXID. My question is, are these legacy (non-SegWit) transactions, i.e. their TXID (which is equal to WTXID) also part of creating a merkle tree for committing in a coinbase transaction or we just take into account SegWit transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wtxids of all transactions are committed to by the witness commitment tree in the coinbase transaction (except the coinbase wtxid itself, as that would be a cyclic dependency). This includes non-witness transactions (for which the txid and wtxid are identical).

Comment: For coinbase transaction I am not calculating its WTIX but taking it as "0x000...0000"?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#commitment-structure